# mount already mounted or busy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount

I have an Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu 12.04) to which I have attached two 250 GB volumes. Inadvertently, the volumes got unmounted. When I tried mounting them again, with the following command,

`sudo mount /dev/xvdg /data`

this is the error I get :

`mount: /dev/xvdg already mounted or /data busy`

Then, I tried un-mounting it as follows :
`umount /dev/xvdg` but it tells me that the volume is not mounted.

`umount: /dev/xvdg is not mounted (according to mtab)`

I tried `lsof` to check for any locks but there weren't any.

The lsblk output is as below :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. What do I need to do to mount the volumes back without losing the data on them?

Comment: Those volumes have been mounted as a single 500GB raid volume using lvm. You need to use `lvscan` to determine the proper device id, and then mount that. Trying to mount the main block device is a *bad idea*

Comment: @Petesh, I ran the command but it gives me the output `No volume groups found`.

Comment: oops, then it's a plain old md device - probably available as `/dev/md127`.

Comment: use `df` to check whether volume `/dev/md127` is mounted.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out. Thanks @Petesh and @mootmoot for pushing me in the right direction. I was trying to mount single volumes instead of a RAID 0 array. The /dev/md127 device was running so I stopped it first with the following command :

`sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md127`

Then I assembled the RAID 0 array :

`sudo mdadm --assemble --uuid <RAID array UUID here> /dev/md0`

Once the /dev/md0 array became active, I mounted it on /data.

Answer (score 0):

Try `umount /dev/xvdg*` and `umount /data` and then
`mount /dev/xvdg1 /data`

Comment: No, it gives the same result. The first two commands give the output "/dev/xvdg is not mounted" and "/data is not mounted". The last command gives the output : `mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'`